# How can i apply theme what is in my mind in the android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

I am really struggling in theming my android application,
i can't understand that how the theme and styles are structured in android, and when to use theme or style for the views.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.HickersWatch" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

this is the default theme provided, now what are these things doing like

and rest them,
where the code is written for  Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar as we are inheriting here.

I think i roughly summarise my issue, if this makes sense to anyone of the 
 viewer of this question so please share some **resource** so that i can  understand these things (android official doc did not helped me this time), or their **own** solution then please share.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I used to style buttons

```
    <style name="button">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_text</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/padding5</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/padding5</item>
        <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="white_button" parent="button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/round_shadow_white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_button_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="blue_button" parent="button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/round_shadow_blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

We nedded 2 kind of buttons a white one and a blue one, the color is the only thing that changed.
So we made a theme named "button" to round the corners, added padding etc..
Then we added an other style named "whit_button" and the parent style is buton, in this style we seted the background color and text color. (same for blue_button).
Now we have a button with rounded corner in white and in blue.
When we want to change the radius of all buttons we have to change it on one place.

I hope this helped.